# Setting choices by foreign keys parent model's field

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I want to set the choices according to a foreign keys parent model's field's value. I.e. "QuestionAnswer" models foreign key "question" is set to model "Question" and that model contains a field "question_type". If the "question_type" value is 1 then set the choices as a, b, c, d, e or if the value is 2, set the choices as f, g, h, i, j. Forms are built as formset but that shouldn't affect how it is done?

First of all do I set the choices as a function and where do I set it? Forms.py, models.py or views.py? 
If in the forms.py do I do it with the **init** method?
How do I get the correct question and the correct choices together?

If you need more info, please ask.

Django version is 1.11.5 and python version is 3.6.0

forms.py

```
class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:  
        model = QuestionAnswer
        fields = ['question', 'answer_text', 'questionnaire_key']
        exclude = [] 
        widgets = {
            'question': HiddenInput,
            'answer_text': RadioSelect(choices=CHOICES,
                                                 attrs={'required': 'True'}),
            'questionnaire_key': HiddenInput
            }
```

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    questionnaire = models.ForeignKey(Questionnaire)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    question_type = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class QuestionAnswer(models.Model):
    questionnaire_key = models.ForeignKey(Questionnaire, null=False, blank=False)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, null=False, blank=False)
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=False, default=None)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer_text
```

In the views I set the initial question data for the formset. And I zip the questions and the formset to be able to render them in table, with question's text on the left, and the answer choices on the right.
views.py

```
def answerpage(request, questionnaire_pk):
    AnswerFormSet = formset_factory(AnswerForm, extra=0)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(questionnaire=questionnaire_pk)
    qname = Questionnaire.objects.get(id=questionnaire_pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        answer_formset = AnswerFormSet(request.POST)
        ...
    else:
        quest_id = request.session.get('questionnaire_key', 0)
        question_data = [{'question': question,
                          'questionnaire_key': quest_id} for question in questions]

        answer_formset = AnswerFormSet(initial=question_data)

    combined = zip(questions, answer_formset)
    context = {
        'combined': combined,
        'questions': questions,
        'answer_formset': answer_formset,
        'qname': qname,
    }
    return render(request, 'main/questionnaire_details2.html', context)
```

**UPDATE:**

Form's init method

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        extra_info = kwargs.pop('questions', None)
        super(AnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['answer_text'].widget = RadioSelect()
        self.fields['answer_text'].choices = get_choice_data(self.instance, extra_info)
```

Set the form_kwargs here:

`formset = AnswerFormSet(form_kwargs={'questions': questions})`

How do I use the formset? If I replace the views `answer_formset = AnswerFormSet(initial=question_data)` with `answer_formset = formset(initial=question_data)` I get `'AnswerFormFormSet' object is not callable` error. I'm guessing that it is the line that I should edit?

Answer (score 0):

You can differentiate three cases:

1. The choices are fix and always the same: Add `choices` kwarg with a fix list of pairs to the model field. These choices will be automatically used by the according field of a `ModelForm`.
2. The choices are generated at runtime, but independent of a particular instance:

   a) `forms.Model[Multiple]ChoiceField`: provide `queryset` kwarg with a `QuerySet` which will be evaluated every time a form instance is created.

   b) `forms.ChoiceField`: provide `choices` param which can be a callable that is called when a form instance is created. This must return a list of pairs similar to 1.
3. The choices are generated at runtime, **and** they depend on the concrete model instance of the form:

Override the form's `__init__`:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['bar_field'].choices = create_complex_choices(self.instance)
```

If you want be able to tweak these choices using extra_information that you only know in your view:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        extra_info = kwargs.pop('extra_info', None)
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['bar_field'].choices = create_complex_choices(self.instance, extra_info)
```

Comment: From my understanding options 1 and 2 aren't going to work as the answer choices are tied to a question and there are at least 4 different choice sets. It leaves me with option 3 and I've updated the question. Thank you for your help.